# Is there a halal type of dating between two muslims?

Tags: halal-haram

Okay, so I have a friend that is Muslim (and so am I) He told me that he liked me, and said ''I know that we can't do anything because of our religion", so I was wondering if there is a halal type of dating where we don't touch each other or anything of some sort.
Lailah.

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you so much!!

Comment: But, is there a type of halal dating?

Comment: "However, meeting up for further recognition for the sake of finding a suitable spouse is allowed (Halal) with the present of the girl's mahram."

Comment: okay got! thank you